# performance of random forest with the size of dataset?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, random-forest

I have two datasets (with 17 features) for the same domain. the first is smaller in size than the second, and a prediction task. I've first tried with several Neural networks configurations, the results were as expected, NNs performed better with the second dataset (the larger one). When I have tried the Random Forest, I've found that it performed much better with the smallest dataset, which I can not understand or explain, because they said that random forest is data-hungry and that Bootstrap resampling is not a cure for small samples.

Can someone explain to me these results?

Comment: How did you measure the performance? Did you do cross-validation? Did you measure the performance in the same way you did for NNs?

Comment: Yes, since dataset is small, I've used 3 folds cross validation even with random forest, and I've have used the same evaluation metrics, and I've compared results for the same fold. In fact I do not care about performance comparison between NN and RF, but I did not understand the behaviour of RF.